# Помогите подправить CSS

Tags: css

Есть блок, который я трансформировал.У него есть атрибут, и при наведении на блок мне нужно чтобы текст из атрибута был ровным. У меня не до конца получилось, может кто то поможет.

**Сейчас**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Нужно**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.pos {
    height: 75px;
    width: 162px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transform: rotateY(-43deg) rotateX(62deg) rotate(26deg);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.pos:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.pos:before {
    content: attr(data-crop);
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateY(212deg) rotateX(116deg) rotate(148deg);
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -72px;
    margin-left: -167px;
    width: 484px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="pos" data-crop="Этот текст должен быть ровным"></div>
```

Comment: Легче сделать на JS. Как на счет решения на jQuery?

Comment: @Crantisz, да, я мог и на js сделать, но думал может можно как то обнулить трансформацию псевдоелемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря ответу [codename0082016](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211218/codename0082016) (в котором есть соседний блок с атрибутом) я сделал чтобы при наведении на блок появлялся `:before` соседнего блока

```css
.pos {
    height: 75px;
    width: 162px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transform: rotateY(-43deg) rotateX(62deg) rotate(26deg);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.pos:hover + .pos2:before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.pos2:before {
    content: attr(data-crop);
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="pos" ></div>
<div class="pos2"  data-crop="Этот текст должен быть ровным"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение не идеальное но оно работает

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoVqWJ

```css
 

  .pos {
    height: 75px;
    width: 162px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transform: rotateY(-43deg) rotateX(62deg) rotate(26deg);
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.pos2 {
    height: 75px;
    width: 162px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    background: hide;
  
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.pos:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.pos2:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.pos:before {
    content: attr(data-crop);
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateY(212deg) rotateX(116deg) rotate(148deg);
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -72px;
    margin-left: -167px;
    width: 484px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.pos2:before {
    content: attr(data-crop);
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="pos" ></div>
<div class="pos2"  data-crop="Этот текст должен быть ровным"></div>
```

Comment: Немного не то, область при наведении должна быть только синий ромб. на сайте просто сетка идет из ромбов, и нужно чтобы у каждого своя область была, но спасибо за помощь)